# Angular object change detection

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a third party angular component which is a table displaying the user data. If the passed object to the table changes, the table updates itself.

How does Angular detect changes to an object? I have following example:

`user.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css'],
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  private _users: User[];
  set users(users: User[]) {
    this._users = users;
  }

  get users(): User[] {
    return this._users;
  }

  constructor() {}

  addUserToTheList(user: User) {

    // this won't be detected as a change to the object
    this.users.push(user);

    // on the other hand, this will
    let userList: User[] = this.users;
    userList.push(user);
    this.users = userList;

  }
}
```

Does that mean I have to completely replace the object to trigger the change detection or am I somehow completely missing the point? Or could it be a problem with the third party library (which is `Clarity Design System`)

Comment: you might to read this [If you think `ngDoCheck` means your component is being checked — read this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5)

Comment: To create a new array instance you can use `this.users = [...this.users, user]` or `this.users = this.users.concat(user)` (both are equivalent after TS compilation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table component you are using is probably implementing `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

This means that the component will treat all input as *immutable* (meaning it can never change), and therefor **only run change detection if the input object is replaced**.

Here is a link explaining it a bit more: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html